# Maps between spaces of modular forms over different congruence subgroups

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

Basically I would like to know if there exists maps similar to the double coset operator (bijective or preserving generating sets for example) between spaces of modular forms over different congruence subgroups. Also, do you think that proving some interesting identities in one space will imply that it is carried under this map to the other space ? 
Thank you :)